# ros2 python package setup for cuda

Tags: ros2, python, rclpy, cuda, gpu

I'm trying to use a YOLOv8 model to make inference in a ros2 python node (ubuntu 22.04, ros2 rolling,Intel® Core™ i7-7700HQ CPU, GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile).

After few tests, I realized that CUDA is not really working and the inference is done by the CPU even if I am calling cuda in the code, for example

```
boxes = results[0].boxes.xywh.cuda()
track_ids = results[0].boxes.id.int().cuda().tolist()
```

I looked for what setup I am missing with ros2 python package and CUDA but I only found examples with cpp packages, like

https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/cuda-in-ros-node-example-code/129130

https://github.com/dusty-nv/ros_deep_learning

Can anyone suggest me some reference to a python package setup or help me here?

Thank you very much for your attention!

[image: output of nvidia-smi]

Comment: Can you add the output of `nvidia-smi` to your question?

Comment: I have updated the question